# How to use multi labels in UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uilabel, iboutlet

I get data from JSON (First name, last name and email) but I'm only able to show first name in `UITableView`. I tried my best but I couldn't make it work. Following is my code.

```
import UIKit

struct User: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let email: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case email = "email"
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    private var dataSource = [User]() {
        didSet {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview.delegate = self

        let url = URL(string: "https://x.com/x.php")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "An error occurred")
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.dataSource = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath)
        let user = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.firstName
        // cell.textLabel?.text = user.lastName  If I write this line then it only shows last name
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using default `UITableViewCell` and there is one more property `detailTextLabel` which you can use with it. But if you want to display more data you need to create custom `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Also, you can set `keyDecodingStrategy` of your `JSONDecoder` to `convertFromSnakeCase` and then you can avoid declaring your own `CodingKeys` enum

Comment: I updated the code and created a custom label, but xcode can't find my label. The code is above. Thanks for your help. @Dharmesh

Comment: You need to cast your `cell` by adding  `as! tableViewCellLabels`

Comment: Where should I write this? In the last func instead of UITableViewCell after -> ?  @Dharmesh

Comment: Just replace `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath)` with `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as! tableViewCellLabels`

Comment: The app crashes and the error is on the new line after as! tableViewCellLabels "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" @Dharmesh

Comment: remove `self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")` and try again

Comment: Oh okay, just new here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle`, like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
    }

    let user = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user.email
    return cell
}
```

You do not need to register cell, so DELETE following line:

```
tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
```

Comment: What if OP want to show 3rd label as described in his question?

Comment: OP seems new and updated his question with several suggested answers :) please have a look at the original question https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55457408/1

Notice OP's original code was `cell.textLabel?.text = user.firstName` and again `cell.textLabel?.text = user.lastName`, so in my sense we don't need a custom uitableviewcell as you were suggesting *First of all you need create custom UITableViewCell*, we can just use `UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitel` and that would do?